# How do I test if a specific player is online?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a command block that detects if me or my friend are online using `/execute`. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test for specific players at specific locations with command blocks](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/351207/how-to-test-for-specific-players-at-specific-locations-with-command-blocks)

Comment: @dly Kind of a stretch. It's not really a selector here.

Answer (score 1):

Simply insert their name instead of a selector in `/execute if`, like this:

```
/execute if entity Horst run …
```

This checks if that player exists in the world, which is only the case if they're currently online on that server/LAN game or playing that world in Singleplayer.